# Custom access/launcher

Tags: window-manager

I'm not sure what to call what I want, so I'll just describe what I want to do.

What I'm doing is setting up an old laptop, with gentoo, for my kids. I want to have some program on there that, with a password, gives access to do homework, to play games for 30 min, watch netflix for an hour, etc.

I can't imagine that there already exists a program that can do that, but it would be less work for me if there was. So I will have to make this launcher program. My question is this, after I make such a program, how do I make it so this program is running at start up and no other programs can be ran from any menus or anything. I have not decided which window manager to use yet. Is there a lite window manager that would help me accomplish this task?

Comment: You want to _limit_ the time your kids have for homework? I can understand limiting the rest but homework? You think they will try and cheat and do their homework for an hour instead of half?

Comment: ah nope, made a mistake type that example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother trying to write a new launcher. Just configure your startup scripts to do what you need:

1. Model the different tasks as different users on the gentoo box: `usenetflix`, `playgame` etc.,
2. Use a [X Display Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)) to create a nice login screen. I'm sure you can find variants that will let you create big friendly icon for all your tasks.
3. In the `~/.Xsession` file, don't even start a Window Manager. Just directly launch whatever application you want that "task account" to use.
4. Finally, to get the autologout behavior, also in each `.Xsession`, use the [`at`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/at.1.php) command to call the appropriate log off script. [This SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/65526) has links to good stuff depending on your environment.

So you might have something like this in your `/home/usenetflix/.Xsession` (double check syntax, I haven't tested this):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "/etc/X11/xdm/Xreset" | at now + 60 minute
firefox netflix.com &
```

Now, nothing is going to prevent your child from just click on "Netflix" again at the login screen unless you add a little more smarts there, say touching a `.lastlogin` file and checking that to see if it should allow startup to continue.

But you should be able to get everything you need without having to write a line of code.

Comment: Wonderful, that is a great idea. That should work out great.